# What is the easy, highly effective way to deal with soreness and exhaustion?

Tags: recovery, energy, soreness, tiredness, relaxation

On and off over the past years I’ve had some periods of pretty intense exercise and while it can feel really good I sometimes actually rue just how tired, sore and exhausted I can get from such a good workout. It would be cool if a workout was hard and felt good afterwards but it did not have to mean you became like an aching human vegetable for the next few days.

I was curious if there is a highly effective and very easy way to deal with muscle soreness and physical fatigue. I am thinking on the level of a medication or supplement, something that easy and deterministic. I don’t know if I should try ibuprofen or a muscle relaxant to try to just feel normal after a workout.

Answer (score 3):

#### It’s possible to “out-kick your coverage” when it comes to fatigue and recovery.

From what it sounds like, you’re simply going too hard. If you’re needing more than a day off to recover from a workout enough to go at it again, then the recovery demand of that workout was greater than your recovery ability. I get it, it’s fun to go hard. But if you want to have a sustainable and effective relationship with exercise, you have to figure out how to balance fatigue and recovery.

If a workout knocks you down for several days, you either went too hard, did too much, or both. I say all this because *there is nothing you can do to recover faster*, except for managing your sleep and nutrition. Eat well and sleep well. Ibuprofen will only mask your pain, it won’t help you recover.  The long term solution is not put yourself in this situation in the first place.